# Using Ansible to run sudo /bin/su - username

Tags: ansible-2.x

I am able to do the following manually -

From my ansible controller server
ssh <>  (using my userid)
sudo /bin/su - <>
..
now run commands as orafmw
...

When trying to do this same step using ansible -

My playbook has the following entry

```
 - role: fmw-software
   become: true
   become_user: 'orafmw'
   become_method: sudo
   become_flags: '/bin/su'
```

This fails as follows -

ansible-playbook  weblogic-fmw-domain.yml

PLAY [Configure Oracle Linux 7.1 with WebLogic 12c R2 domain] ******************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [weblogic]

TASK [fmw-software : Create installer directory] *******************************
fatal: [weblogic]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
        to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/ansible-weblogic-fmw-infra-12c-R2-master/weblogic-fmw-domain.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
weblogic                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Can anyone point what I might be doing wrong here ? 
The docs suggest - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

" Only one method may be enabled per host
Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user, you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be able to su directly to it (the same for pbrun, pfexec or other supported methods). "

Is this above section applicable for my usecase ?

Answer (score 1):

The `become_flags` seem to be redundant to achieving your goal of running commands as the "orafmw" account.  As a quick test if you do this:

```
 - role: fmw-software
   become: true
   become_user: 'orafmw'
   become_method: sudo
   command: touch /tmp/whomadethis
```

Does the new file "/tmp/whomadethis" get created on the remote machine and owned by the `orafmw` account?  If so, then replace the call that the `command:` module makes with the commands you need to run.

Better yet, don't use `command:` module, rather use built-in Ansible modules with the `become_*` options set as needed.

Comment: The security in my organisation does not allow me to run sudo orafmw, I need to instead run sudo /bin/su - orafmw, I dont get challenged for password. With the options you have provided I get the error "sudo: a password is required\r\n"

Comment: Interesting, so are you able to use just `become_method: su` instead of `sudo`?

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the remote servers that might help shed some light from that side?

Comment: Can you run the playbook with the `-c paramiko` option?  There's a Github issue that mentions this (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14426) as a workaround as well as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616021/ansible-sudo-hangs-after-5-tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - I have already tried become_method: su and -c paramiko  with no luck. I feel that the section in the documentation that I referred about " sudo /bin/su - " could be why I am not getting much success. I have asked my linux admin to change the sudo rule to allow ansible to run all commands.

Comment: we had to add the following in the sudoers file  ALL=(orafmw) NOPASSWD: ALL  for the code to be able to sudo as orafmw without being challenged for a password.

Comment: Good - the modification to the sudoers file was my original comment plan, glad it worked out for you.  I should have added it originally - the you could have accepted it as the answer.